# Problems with timesyncd or networkd

Tags: debian, systemd

I am using Raspbian Jessie and I want to set up time synchronization.

What I did is:

*enabled* `systemd-timesyncd`

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

*enabled* `systemd-networkd`

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
```

*put local servers in* `timesyncd.conf`

*and created* `/etc/systemd/network/wireless.network`

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
```

It seems that `timesyncd` is working, but with error.  Command

```
sudo grep time /var/log/syslog
```

returns bunch of errors

```
May 16 22:11:36 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[3023]: Timed out waiting for reply from 193.2.78.228:123 (0.si.pool.ntp.org).
```

On the other hand command

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd systemd-networkd
```

returns

```
�� systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-05-16 21:47:11 CEST; 31min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 3023 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Idle."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           ������3023 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

�� systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-05-16 11:36:41 CEST; 10h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 1666 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           ������1666 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
```

The response for `networkd` is is always `Processing requests...`, which to me looks suspicious.

I have lost at least 30 hours of my life for this simple problem of time synchronization.  Before that I tried to use (unsuccessfully) `ntpdate` ([see](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47542/raspberry-pi-wont-update-time) ).  For a test I installed time synchronization for Windows on the very same LAN using the very same NTP servers.  It took me 3 minutes and it is working like a charm.  So much about Linux being an good alternative for Windows for personal use.

Please help me, I almost lost all hope.  No idea what to do next...

Comment: Make sure that UDP port 123 is open on your firewall config.

Comment: @GAD3R It is open.  I am using Windows on the same network and time update there works like a charm.

Comment: You are not configuring your wireless interface anywhere. Yes you are configuring DHCP, but not the connection and authentication to an access point. With a wired ethernet card you would be done here, but for wireless you need to bring wpa_supplicant.service or similar into the mix.

Comment: I know some time have passed but I had similar issue due to proxy on my network. Did you have any? Did `ping 0.si.pool.ntp.org` return anything?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. If exist file localtime:

```
mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime_old

ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Ljubljana /etc/localtime
```

put servers in `timesyncd.conf`:

```
   server 1.si.pool.ntp.org
   server 1.europe.pool.ntp.org
   server 0.europe.pool.ntp.org
```

and

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Check if it works.

**Other idea:**

Maybe timesyncd is runned after networkd and then waits for change. All you have to do is

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

If this works, try create a script start during the boot process.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sleep 20
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Comment: Neither is working.  I also restarted `timesyncd` to get new servers.  There is no question that `timesyncd` is working, that is why I get errors `Timed out waiting for reply.`  Probably the question is whether `timesyncd` can work with debian's `NetworkManager` or maybe `NetworkManager` should be turned off and replaced by `networkd`.